# Android - can you have multiple variable types for single method() parameter?

Tags: android, methods

Can you have two or more variable types for a single method() parameter?

At the moment, you can do:

```
method(String string, int int, etc...) {
}
```

What if you wanted to do something like

```
method(String or int stringint) {
}
```

can this be done?

Comment: I want to do this because my method needs to check if Address or LatLng is being passed to it. I don't want to have two paramaters for it. If it's Address, it need to convert to LatLng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
private boolean function(String str){
    // Do stuff
}
private boolean function(int intStr){
    String str = convertToString(intStr);
    return function(str);
}
```

Avoids unnecessary classes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just overload the method signature.

```
public void someMethod(string argument){
}

public void someMethod(int argument){
}
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters I might be missing something.  Are you referring to this thread?  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you have to stick to one single parameter you can use a wrapper, which contains two fiels:

```
public class MyWrapper
{
   String stringValue;
   int intValue;
}

public void someMethod(MyWrapper arg)
{
    if(arg.stringField != null)
    {
       // do something with the string
    }

    /* checking for the default value 0 makes no sense here, since it
       might be a value you actually want to pass - The first conditional
       statement covers the case you actually only passed a string
    */
    else
    {
       // do something with the int
    }
}
```